# Map JSON jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type '' from Array value

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hello Everyone I am having Trouble Parsing a JSON.
SO I recieve a JSON from a URL and most of the parsing works just fine but there is an array in there that I can seperate but when I try to Parse it into a List it doesnt Work and gives

jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type '' from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)  at [Source: (String)"["2020-01-01 00:00:00",-4.6]"; line: 1, column: 1]

```
//The main code
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");
        ArrayList<TempTimestamp> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(mapper.readValue(array.get(0).toString(), TempTimestamp.class));
        ArrayList<TempTimestamp> list = mapper.readValue(array.toString() , new TypeReference<ArrayList<TempTimestamp>>(){});
```

```
public class TempTimestamp{
            public String date;
            public double temperature;

            public TempTimestamp(String date, double temperature) {
                this.date = date;
                this.temperature = temperature;
            }
        }
```

The format of the JSON I recieve is :

```
... , "data": [["2020-01-01 00:00:00",-4.6],["2020-01-02 00:00:00",-4.4],["2020-01-03 00:00:00",3.6],["2020-01-04 00:00:00",2.8],["2020-01-05 00:00:00",0.9], ...
```

I've tried several version to parse it but I just dont seem to get it I must overlook or misunderstand someting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a simplified version of your json like below:

```
{
  "data": [
            ["2020-01-01 00:00:00",-4.6],
            ["2020-01-02 00:00:00",-4.4]
          ]
}
```

You have an array of arrays you want to be converted to `TempTimestamp` class instances: this is not the default behaviour of the jackson deserialization because the jackson library expects to find json objects and instead it find arrays of values. To deserialize a json array of values to an object there is the specific [`JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation:

```
@Data
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class TempTimestamp {

    private String date;
    private double temperature;

}
```

Then you can convert your json array of arrays like below:

```
String json = """
                 {
                   "data": [
                             ["2020-01-01 00:00:00",-4.6],
                             ["2020-01-02 00:00:00",-4.4]
                           ]
                 }
              """;
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json).at("/data");
TempTimestamp[] data = mapper.convertValue(node, TempTimestamp[].class);
//it prints the two expected objects
//[TempTimestamp(date=2020-01-01 00:00:00, temperature=-4.6),
//TempTimestamp(date=2020-01-02 00:00:00, temperature=-4.4)]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. First of all it worked but you also explained it in a way I understood what I did wrong!